# Evans PDE, Problem 8 Chapter 2 clarification on $|x-y|$

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Hi I am attempting problem 8 (Chapt2 Evans PDE). Again I found the solution on the internet.

[enter link description here](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/kpromisl/math849/HW2A.pdf)

I understood much of everything of the proof except for one line.
" Since $x=\lambda e_n$ and $y\in\partial\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$ we have $|x-y|=\sqrt{\lambda^2+|y|^2}$."

I just cannot see how this equality holds. Could anyone help?

Comment: Here's my guess: since the dimension of the space is $n$, we have $e_{n} = (0,0,0, \dots, 0, 1)$, where there are $n$ coordinates.  Then $\lambda e_{n} = (0,0,0,\dots,0, \lambda)$, right?  Now, $y$ is on the boundary of $\Bbb R^{n}_{+}$.  I assume that means the last coordinate is $0$, depending on how you define $\Bbb R^{n}_{+}$ -- how did the book define it?  If the last coordinate IS $0$, then $|x - y|^{2} = (y_{1}^{2} + \dots + y_{n-1}^{2} + \lambda^{2}) = (y_{1}^{2} + \dots + y_{n-1}^{2} + 0 + \lambda^{2}) = (|y|^{2} + \lambda^{2})$. Again, I'm assuming $y = (y_{1}, \dots, y_{n - 1}, 0)$.

Comment: The book defines $\mathbb{R}_{+}^n=\{x=(x_1,\cdots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n|x_n>0\}$. However, $\partial\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$ does not seem to be defined anywhere in the book. But according some googling I found $\partial\mathbb{R}_{+}^n=\{x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n):\,x_n=0\}$. And here $y\in \partial\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$, so what you suggested seems making sense...

Comment: If $R^{n}_{+}$ is as you define, then it should make intuitive sense to you that the *boundary* of this space, denoted by $\partial R^{n}_{+}$, is the set with $x_{n} = 0$.  You don't have a picture of this in your mind?

Comment: @user46944 your answer is correct because of the construction of $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ as the half-space. I would suggest you writing that as an answer below so that it can be accepted.

Comment: yes 46944, i saw the picture. Thank you

Comment: @math101 Ok, but if you are still confused about the boundary I suggest you ask someone that can draw a nice picture for you.  Then it will make sense as to why the boundary is this.  I posted an answer.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Done.

Comment: There is no one around can help this way.

Comment: @math101 Check out this image: http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/partderiv/limits9.gif

Comment: Now picture in 3D, so imagine $\Bbb R^{3}$.  Think about the vertical axis as the 3rd coordinate.  $R^{3}_{+}$ is the set of $(x,y,z)$ such that $z > 0$, so you should picture everything *above* the $XY$-plane.  That is our set.  Now imagine the boundary just as in the picture I sent you.  Is it clear that this boundary is the $XY$-plane itself?  For every point on the $XY$-place, and every open neighborhood around the point, the nbhd intersects with $R^{3}_{+}$.

Comment: @user46944: thanks for that. exactly the sort of things i need to practice to be more comfortable...still have 3 more chapters in Evans to work on...don't know when I can get there. There for all that by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dimension of the Euclidean space is $n$, we have $e_{n} = (0,0, \dots, 0, 1)$, where there are $n$ coordinates. Then $\lambda e_{n} = (0,0, \dots, 0, \lambda)$.

Since $\Bbb R^{n}_{+} = \{(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \mid x_{n} > 0 \}$, then the boundary of this space is $\partial \Bbb R^{n}_{+} = \{ (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \mid x_{n} = 0 \}$.  Then since if $x = \lambda e_{n}$ and $y = (y_{1}, \dots,  y_{n-1}, 0)$, we have $x - y = (y_{1}, \dots,  y_{n-1}, \lambda)$, so $$|x - y| = \sqrt{y_{1}^{2} + \dots + y_{n - 1}^{2} + \lambda^{2}} = \sqrt{y_{1}^{2} + \dots + y_{n - 1}^{2} + 0 + \lambda^{2}} = \sqrt{|y|^{2} + \lambda^{2}}.$$